# Python regex doesn't match what other regex tools do match

Tags: python, regex

I have following code:

```
currencies = ['USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CHF', 'SEK', 'DKK', 'NOK', 'SGD', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'TWD', 'NZD', 'CNY', 'KRW', 'INR', 'CAD', 'VEF', 'EGP', 'THB', 'IDR', 'PKR', 'MYR', 'PHP', 'MXN', 'VND', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'PLN', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'ILS', 'ARS', 'CLP', 'BRL', 'RUB', 'QAR', 'AED', 'COP', 'PEN', 'CNH', 'KWD', 'SAR']
exclusive_regexp = ".*\/" + ".*|.*\/".join(currencies) + ".*"
searching_regexp = "^(?! (" + exclusive_regexp + ")$)(.*\/.*)$"
searching_regexp = re.compile(searching_regexp) 


with open('raw.txt', 'r') as unprocessed_ticks:
    print(re.findall(searching_regexp, unprocessed_ticks.read()))
```

It should find all strings that can be matched with produced regex.

I probed generated regex with regex101.com online tool. it works with python flavor. But in real code it doesn't match anything:
https://regex101.com/r/70uiuE/7
Why it can happen?

Comment: I suspect `re.findall(searching_regexp, unprocessed_ticks.read(), re.M)`

Comment: Isnt \ an escape char in python so you need to double escape it?

Comment: What text do you expect this to match? The slash doesn't need to be backslash-escaped in Python.

Comment: The `.*` you so liberally sprinkle probably causes this to match way *more* than you intend.

Comment: I think `exclusive_regexp = "/(?:{})".format("|".join(currencies))` with `searching_regexp = "^(?! .*" + exclusive_regexp + ")[^/]*/.*$"` would also work. Just pass `re.M` flag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works, thanks! Can you please form it like an answer? I will close a question with choosing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- There is no need to escape `/` in Python (and any other) *string* patterns (`/` should only be escaped when the regex is set via a regex literal with slashes used as regex delimiters)
- You are overusing `.*` pattern, you should minimize the number of alternatives that match at the same location in string
- For `^` and `$` to match start and end of a line, you must pass the `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` flag to the regex.

I suggest changing the regexps to

```
exclusive_regexp = r"/(?:{})".format("|".join(currencies))
searching_regexp = re.compile(r"^(?! .*" + exclusive_regexp + ")[^/\n]*/.*", re.M)
```

and then

```
print(searching_regexp.findall(unprocessed_ticks.read()))
```

The `exclusive_regexp` regex will look tidier now (`/(?:USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)`) and the `searching_regexp` will match any string that starts with 0+ chars other than `/`, then has a `/` and then any amount of any chars but newline (`[^/\n]*/.*`) that does not start with a space, `/` and a currency value.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eJ6yxm).